# Logic Gate Advice - Rearranging bits and anticipating the outcome

Tags: nand2tetris

In practice, when there's so many possible combinations using gates to arrive to a solution, what's some advice when analyzing bit behavior?

For instance, what's the general thought process to be able to anticipate how bits are going to flip in our favor using my non-code example:

If I have 2 Nand gate outputs tested 6 times:

110111 (let's call this first set)

101111 (let's call this second set)

You see the 0 instances above?  Had they been aligned in the same output instance, I would have finished my gate logic.  However, they're misaligned by one output instance.  I felt I was close, but wasn't sure what to do.

I had to gate "shuffle" the bits of the first set like a deck of cards then compare it back to the original first set and eventually fulfilled the condition I needed for my gates to work.  It felt like luck.  I'm sure there's a better way to think about this.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question, perhaps it is more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com/. Or if dealing with actual hardware gates, then https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: HDLs are programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to give you advice because your example is not specific and it is hard to understand exactly what your concern is. StackOverflow works best when you post a specific problem with actual code (HDL in this case).

With regards to optimization, it all depends on what you want to optimize for -- for example: code readability/simplicity / minimum number of gates / minimum gate delays (not an issue in NAND2Tetris but often is in real life).

As a general philosophy, I tend towards readability and simplicity first -- get something working that is understandable. Once you've got the assignment done, if you have extra time you can flex and try for minimizing the number of gates.

There are, btw, design tools that will take an arbitrary truth table and generate a minimal-gate solution.

Comment: Noted.  Also removed tags unrelated to non-N2T.

The last part regarding design tools--probably would've saved me a couple hours for the jump bits and ALU however it takes away from the learning process.  

Point is, since your familiar with the course, is that I got lucky making an "elegant" solution for the jump bits and ALU.  Was seeking advice on how to see patterns instead of "reshuffling" bits until something works.

Comment: The idea is not to reshuffle, but to create simple gates and logic, and build those together to larger and larger curcuits. There is nothing random about it. If you are just trying combinations, your code could work by accident for selected input only.

Comment: I understand now what I did.  I was "truth tabling" gate effectiveness and noticing bit patterns instead of purely applying gates in a practical, logical manner.  I should get better at the latter.